# Exceptions logged with RPC are throwing IncompatibleRemoteServiceException

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2

So right, the basics, this is running on GWT2.5.0 / JDK1.6 and set up more or less as the docs have it set up

gwt.xml

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />

<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler"
    value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler"
    value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

and I'm forcing the exception with the following code, just a simple NullPointException

```
     try {
        Level n = null;
        n.getName();
      } catch (NullPointerException ex) {             
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Null Exception Hit", ex);
      }
```

But for some reason this is thrown when the exception is thrown to the server

```
[WARN] remoteLogging: An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: Type 'com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SerializableThrowable' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer. For security purposes, this type will not be deserialized.
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:323)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
```

The RPC servlet is properly configured and if I throw just the message and not the exception it logs back to the server just fine.

According to the docs on remote server logging this should "just work" and I don't see why this is getting thrown. It seems to me SerializableThrowable should by definition be serializable. I know you  have to jump through some hoops to have your own classes be serializable, but everything I've read says I should be able to toss exceptions back to the server without issue. Any ideas? It looks like since 2.5.0 serializableThrowable has been moved to com.google.gwt.core.shared.SerializableThrowable, but I don't think that's doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Exception's super class is  `Throwable` and it Implementing `java.io.Serializable`

*important point to note is that none of the classes that implement java.io.Serializable in the full Java JRE implement java.io.Serializable in GWT's emulated JRE. What this means is that **types that implement java.io.Serializable in the JRE like Throwable, or StackTraceElement won't be able to transfer across the wire through GWT RPC since the client won't be able to serialize/deserialize them**. However, this isn't an issue for other types like String, Number, etc... that don't implement java.io.Serializable in the emulated JRE but have custom field serializers so that they can be properly serialized.*

[GWT serialization policy](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server?hl=fr#Does_the_GWT_RPC_system_support_the_use_of_java.io.Serializable)

Comment: It's not complaining about Throwable though, it's identifying the thrown exception as Type 'com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SerializableThrowable' and complaining it's not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable'

Comment: This may happened due to runtime.What i am aware is GWT can not handle unchecked exceptions which are not serialized that extends from RuntimeException.

Comment: And as a side note what is the need behind throwing the exception to server?(http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2012/06/11/7-tips-for-exception-handling-in-gwt/)?

Comment: Right, I've followed the directions at that link and my code (including the way I throw the exception) is taken directly from

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging#Remote_Logging

and

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging#Loggers_Handlers_and_the_Root_Logger

The stacktraces are being sent back in order to help find and resolve bugs without requiring our users to email us errors on their own.

Comment: Seems like buggy,May be placing a ticket will grab some attention from implementers.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I'm just going to loop through the stacktrace, convert it to a giant string, and pass that back since I can use logger.log(level,msg) with no issue. Hacky, but at least it works.